# Profiling a blender plugin?

Tags: python, add-on

Did anyone mess with profiler & blender plugins?
If so, could you share your experience, and how you implemented your profiler in your plugin? Bonus Points if it is a non-intrusive way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find hereby a dedicated profiler plugin
https://devtalk.blender.org/t/plugin-profiler-benchmark-debug-your-bpy-work/25787

Answer (score 4):

I found two potential ways of implementing a profiler in a blender plugin:

- 1: create your own profiler, this can be done, in theory, by procedurally injecting a wrapper on every functions found on your plugin modules (quite tricky as blender will check for functions positional arguments)
- 2: use the `cProfile` module. It has the advantage of being natively integrated in Python, therefore the implementation is done on a much lower level. the data can then be dumped & imported in visualization apps such as [tuna](https://pypi.org/project/tuna/) or [snakeviz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/) ( use `pip install` first of course)

Find hereby two profilers class with an implementation proposal/example

```
#TODO: cProfile filter plugin modules only?
#TODO: cProfile real time printing maybe?
#TODO: create a plugin out of this 


#   .oooooo.   ooooooooo.                       .o88o.  o8o  oooo
#  d8P'  `Y8b  `888   `Y88.                     888 `"  `"'  `888
# 888           888   .d88' oooo d8b  .ooooo.  o888oo  oooo   888   .ooooo.
# 888           888ooo88P'  `888""8P d88' `88b  888    `888   888  d88' `88b
# 888           888          888     888   888  888     888   888  888ooo888
# `88b    ooo   888          888     888   888  888     888   888  888    .o
#  `Y8bood8P'  o888o        d888b    `Y8bod8P' o888o   o888o o888o `Y8bod8P'


class cProfiler: 

    app = None

    #EventProfiler Parmeters: 

    #print stats to console?
    outputprint = False 

    #updatelog, will overwrite old log
    outputlog = True 

    #log name
    logname = "profile"

    #try to run vizualisation sofware?
    runviz = True 

    #snakeviz|tuna ? use "pip install x" first
    vizapp = "snakeviz" 


    @classmethod
    def start(cls):

        import cProfile

        print("\n","Starting cProfiler","\n")
        cls.app = cProfile.Profile()
        cls.app.enable()

        return None

    @classmethod
    def end(cls,):

        if (cls.app is None): 
            return None

        print("\n","Ending cProfiler","\n")

        import pstats
        import io 

        cls.app.disable()
        s = io.StringIO()
        ps = pstats.Stats(cls.app, stream=s).sort_stats(pstats.SortKey.CUMULATIVE)

        if (cls.outputlog or cls.runviz):
            
            import os
            import bpy
                    
            filename = f"{cls.logname}.log"
            localpath = os.path.dirname(bpy.utils.resource_path("LOCAL"))
            path = os.path.join(localpath,filename)

            print("\n",f"cProfiler Dumping Stats : {path}","\n")
            ps.dump_stats(path)

            if cls.runviz:

                import shlex
                import subprocess

                command = f"python -m {cls.vizapp} {filename}"
                print("\n",f"Trying to run {cls.vizapp.title()} : {command}","\n")

                try:
                    #os.system(command)
                    subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command))
                
                except Exception as e: 

                    print("\n","VizApp failed, did you tried pip install?\nif so please check our source code and see if your OS is properly supported","\n")
        
        if cls.outputprint:

            ps.print_stats()
            print(s.getvalue())

        return None



# ooooo   ooooo                                                                         .o8
# `888'   `888'                                                                        "888
#  888     888   .ooooo.  ooo. .oo.  .oo.    .ooooo.  ooo. .oo.  .oo.    .oooo.    .oooo888   .ooooo.
#  888ooooo888  d88' `88b `888P"Y88bP"Y88b  d88' `88b `888P"Y88bP"Y88b  `P  )88b  d88' `888  d88' `88b
#  888     888  888   888  888   888   888  888ooo888  888   888   888   .oP"888  888   888  888ooo888
#  888     888  888   888  888   888   888  888    .o  888   888   888  d8(  888  888   888  888    .o
# o888o   o888o `Y8bod8P' o888o o888o o888o `Y8bod8P' o888o o888o o888o `Y888""8o `Y8bod88P" `Y8bod8P'

# This version still need more work,
# wrapping is very tricky


class EventProfiler: 

    #main registry 
    registry = {}

    #EventProfiler Parmeters: 

    #please define your plugin main module here, it should be the name of your folder
    plugin_main_module = ""

    #print all event?
    event_prints = True
    print_extra_info = False

    #end() parameter
    outputprint=True

    #ignore parameters, typically ui functions/modules
    ignore_fcts = []
    ignore_module = []

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, fct, exec_time=0):
        """update internal registry with exec time and calls"""

        key = f"{fct.__module__}.{fct.__name__}"
        r = cls.registry.get(key)

        if (r is None): 
            cls.registry[key] = {}
            cls.registry[key]["calls"] = 0
            cls.registry[key]["runtime"] = 0
            r = cls.registry[key]

        r["calls"] +=1
        r["runtime"] += exec_time

        return None 

    @classmethod
    def event_printer(cls, fct, runtime):
        """print event to console"""

        if not cls.event_prints: 
            return None 
        if cls.print_extra_info:
              extra_info = f"\n     POS_ARG: {args}\n     WK_ARG:{kwargs}\n     RETURN:{r}\n     RUNTIME:{runtime:.4f}s"
        else: extra_info = ""

        return print(f"PROFILER : {fct.__module__}.{fct.__name__}",extra_info) 

    @classmethod
    def wrapper(cls, fct):
        """wrap-profile any functions with our benchmark & counter"""

        #ignore some function?
        if (fct.__name__ in cls.ignore_fcts):
            return fct

        #Blender might check your function.__code__.co_argcount. this make wrapping way more complex
        #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73601340/how-to-wrap-a-function-with-accurate-code-argcount?noredirect=1#comment129973896_73601340

        #so fct.__code__.co_argcount will be accurate
        if (fct.__defaults__ is not None):
              posonly = fct.__code__.co_argcount - len(fct.__defaults__)
        else: posonly = fct.__code__.co_argcount

        #ignore some function?
        if (fct.__name__ in cls.ignore_fcts):
            return fct

        #debug function? 
        # if (fct.__name__=="_global_to_surface_space"):
        #     print("\n\n","_DEBUG_"*100,"\n\n")
        #     print("_global_to_surface_space")
        #     print("fct.__code__.co_argcount : ",fct.__code__.co_argcount)
        #     print("len(fct.__defaults__) : ",len(fct.__defaults__))
        #     print("posonly : ",posonly)
        #     print("\n\n","_DEBUG_"*100,"\n\n")

        import functools
        import time 

        if (posonly==0):

            @functools.wraps(fct)
            def inner(*args,**kwargs):
                t = time.time()
                r = fct(*args,**kwargs)
                runtime = time.time()-t
                cls.register(fct, exec_time=runtime,)
                cls.event_printer(fct, runtime,)
                return r
        
        elif (posonly==1):

            @functools.wraps(fct)
            def inner(a,*args,**kwargs):
                args += (a,)
                t = time.time()
                r = fct(*args,**kwargs)
                runtime = time.time()-t
                cls.register(fct, exec_time=runtime,)
                cls.event_printer(fct, runtime,)
                return r
        
        elif (posonly==2):

            @functools.wraps(fct)
            def inner(a,b,*args,**kwargs):
                args += a,b
                t = time.time()
                r = fct(*args,**kwargs)
                runtime = time.time()-t
                cls.register(fct, exec_time=runtime,)
                cls.event_printer(fct, runtime,)
                return r
        
        elif (posonly==3):

            @functools.wraps(fct)
            def inner(a,b,c,*args,**kwargs):
                args += a,b,c
                t = time.time()
                r = fct(*args,**kwargs)
                runtime = time.time()-t
                cls.register(fct, exec_time=runtime,)
                cls.event_printer(fct, runtime,)
                return r
        
        elif (posonly==4):

            @functools.wraps(fct)
            def inner(a,b,c,d,*args,**kwargs):
                args += a,b,c,d
                t = time.time()
                r = fct(*args,**kwargs)
                runtime = time.time()-t
                cls.register(fct, exec_time=runtime,)
                cls.event_printer(fct, runtime,)
                return r
        
        elif (posonly==5):

            @functools.wraps(fct)
            def inner(a,b,c,d,e,*args,**kwargs):
                args += a,b,c,d,e
                t = time.time()
                r = fct(*args,**kwargs)
                runtime = time.time()-t
                cls.register(fct, exec_time=runtime,)
                cls.event_printer(fct, runtime,)
                return r
        
        elif (posonly==6):

            @functools.wraps(fct)
            def inner(a,b,c,d,e,f,*args,**kwargs):
                args += a,b,c,d,e,f
                t = time.time()
                r = fct(*args,**kwargs)
                runtime = time.time()-t
                cls.register(fct, exec_time=runtime,)
                cls.event_printer(fct, runtime,)
                return r
        
        elif (posonly==7):

            @functools.wraps(fct)
            def inner(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,*args,**kwargs):
                args += a,b,c,d,e,f,g
                t = time.time()
                r = fct(*args,**kwargs)
                runtime = time.time()-t
                cls.register(fct, exec_time=runtime,)
                cls.event_printer(fct, runtime,)
                return r
        
        elif (posonly==8):

            @functools.wraps(fct)
            def inner(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,*args,**kwargs):
                args += a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
                t = time.time()
                r = fct(*args,**kwargs)
                runtime = time.time()-t
                cls.register(fct, exec_time=runtime,)
                cls.event_printer(fct, runtime,)
                return r
        
        elif (posonly==9):

            @functools.wraps(fct)
            def inner(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,*args,**kwargs):
                args += a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
                t = time.time()
                r = fct(*args,**kwargs)
                runtime = time.time()-t
                cls.register(fct, exec_time=runtime,)
                cls.event_printer(fct, runtime,)
                return r
        
        elif (posonly==10):

            @functools.wraps(fct)
            def inner(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,*args,**kwargs):
                args += a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
                t = time.time()
                r = fct(*args,**kwargs)
                runtime = time.time()-t
                cls.register(fct, exec_time=runtime,)
                cls.event_printer(fct, runtime,)
                return r
        
        else:
            raise Exception("PROFILER_ERROR >>> my_wrapper() do not support more than 10 positional argument")

        return inner

    @classmethod
    def start(cls):
        """inject the profiler wrapper for every functions for every modules of our plugin
        used for benchmark or debugging purpose only"""
        
        import sys
        import types

        print("\n","Injecting EventProfiler","\n")

        def is_function(obj):
            """check if given object is a function"""
            return isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType)
                
        #for all modules in sys.modules
        for mod_k,mod in sys.modules.copy().items():
            
            #separate module componments names
            mod_list = mod_k.split('.')
            
            #fileter module that isn't ours
            if (mod_list[0]!=cls.plugin_main_module):
                continue
            #ignore main __init__ module
            if ((len(mod_list)==1) and (mod_list[0]==cls.plugin_main_module)):
                continue
            #ignore some modules?
            if any([m in cls.ignore_module for m in mod_list]):
                continue
                        
            #for each objects found in module
            for ele_k,ele in mod.__dict__.items():
                
                #if it does not have a name, skip
                if (not hasattr(ele,"__name__")):
                    continue
                
                #we have a global function
                elif is_function(ele):
                    print(f"- Inject : Local-Fct : {mod_k}.{ele_k}")
                    mod.__dict__[ele_k] = cls.wrapper(ele)

                #then we have a homebrewed class?
                elif repr(ele).startswith(f"<class '{cls.plugin_main_module}."):
                    for class_k,class_e in ele.__dict__.items():
                        if is_function(class_e):
                            print(f"- Inject : Class-Fct : {mod_k}.{ele_k}.{class_k}")
                            setattr( mod.__dict__[ele_k], class_k, cls.wrapper(class_e),) #class.__dict__ are mapping proxies, need to assign this way
                continue

        print("")

        return None 

    @classmethod
    def end(cls,):
        """calculate averages & optionally print output"""

        print("\n","Generating EventProfiler Sum","\n")

        for k,v in cls.registry.copy().items():
            cls.registry[k]["averagetime"] = v["runtime"]/v["calls"]

        if cls.outputprint: 

            print("\n","Outputing EventProfiler Result","\n")

            sorted_registry = dict(sorted(cls.registry.items(), key=lambda item:item[1]["runtime"], reverse=False))

            for k,v in sorted_registry.items():
                print("\n",k,":")
                for a,val in v.items():
                    print(" "*6,a,":",val)

        return None


# ooooo                              oooo                                                        .  
# `888'                              `888                                                      .o8  
#  888  ooo. .oo.  .oo.   oo.ooooo.   888   .ooooo.  ooo. .oo.  .oo.    .ooooo.  ooo. .oo.   .o888oo
#  888  `888P"Y88bP"Y88b   888' `88b  888  d88' `88b `888P"Y88bP"Y88b  d88' `88b `888P"Y88b    888  
#  888   888   888   888   888   888  888  888ooo888  888   888   888  888ooo888  888   888    888  
#  888   888   888   888   888   888  888  888    .o  888   888   888  888    .o  888   888    888 .
# o888o o888o o888o o888o  888bod8P' o888o `Y8bod8P' o888o o888o o888o `Y8bod8P' o888o o888o   "888"
#                          888
#                         o888o

#Implementation proposal, in main __init__.register/unregister

"""

#Homebrewed profiler: Best for live prints / debugging

from . profiler import EventProfiler

#Options

EventProfiler.plugin_main_module = "Scatter5" #filter modules, cannot be ""
EventProfiler.event_prints = True #print live execution?
EventProfiler.print_extra_info = False #print arguments, return values, & execution time of function?
EventProfiler.outputprint = False #print final statistics in console?
EventProfiler.ignore_module = ["ui"] #ignore some modules ? (ui drawing fct?)
EventProfiler.ignore_fcts = [ #ignore some functions (ui drawing fct?)
    "is_compatible_instance",
    "get_psy_active",
    "is_category_used",
    "is_synchronized",
    "is_locked",
    "get_surfaces",
    "get_scatter_mod",
    "translate",
    "cust_icon",
    "get_s_surface_main_features",
    "get_s_distribution_main_features",
    "get_s_mask_main_features",
    "get_s_scale_main_features",
    "get_s_rot_main_features",
    "get_s_pattern_main_features",
    "get_s_abiotic_main_features",
    "get_s_proximity_main_features",
    "get_s_ecosystem_main_features",
    "get_s_push_main_features",
    "get_s_wind_main_features",
    "get_s_instances_main_features",
    "get_s_visibility_main_features",
    "get_s_display_main_features",
    ]

#cProfile profiler: Great for benchmark & final statistics with visualizer app

from . profiler import cProfiler

#Options

cProfiler.outputprint = False #print final stats in console?
cProfiler.outputlog = True #write log needed for viz sofware (will overwrite log with same names)
cProfiler.logname = "my_benchmark" #name of the log file? (path will be located in your local blender installation, where blender.exe is located)
cProfiler.runviz = True #run vizualisation sofware? please fit requirements first
cProfiler.vizapp = "snakeviz" #which viz app to call ? snakeviz or  tuna ? -> use "pip install xxx" first

#Turn Profiler on/off here
use_profiler = True 



def register():

    if use_profiler:
        cProfiler.start()
        EventProfiler.start()

    for m in main_modules:
        m.register()
    
    return None


def unregister():

    for m in reversed(main_modules):
        m.unregister()

    if use_profiler:
        cProfiler.end()
        EventProfiler.end()

    return None


"""
```